# Error al subir imagen PHP + AJAX + JQUERY

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

tengo un formulario en donde quiero subir imagenes, he leído acerca de ello y yo estoy intentando con `HTML5 + AJAX + JQUERY + PHP`

Entonces tengo el siguiente código le pertenece a un MODAL en donde voy a capturar los datos del formulario:

**FORM**

```
<form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <!-- Modal body -->
    <br>
    <img src="../img/img-services/img-service-2.jpg" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Cinque Terre" width="100" height="100"> 
    <br>
    <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
      <button class="upload-btn">Upload a file</button>
      <input type="file" name="img_url" id="img_url" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

      <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="" hidden required="">
      <label>Service Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value=""  onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)" onblur="limpia()" class="form-control validate" required="" placeholder="Enter Service Name">
      <p id="errorName" style="color:red; display: none;"></p>
      <label>Service Type</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="id_tipo_servicio" name="id_tipo_servicio">
        <option value="0">Select option...</option>
        <?php
          while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$valores[id_tipo_servicio].'">'.$valores[ts_nombre].'</option>';
          }
        ?>
      </select>
      <p id="errorSelect" style="color:red; display: none;"></p>
      <label>Description</label>
      <textarea id="desc" name="desc" class="form-control validate" required="" placeholder="Enter Service Description"></textarea>
      <p id="errorDesc" style="color:red; display: none;"></p>
      <label>Cost</label>
      <input type="number" id="cost" name="cost" value="" class="form-control validate" required="" placeholder="Enter Cost">
      <p id="errorCost" style="color:red; display: none;"></p>
      <div class="spinner-grow text-primary" style="display: none;" role="status" id="showLoad">
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="saveButton" onclick="doAction()" style="display: none"><span id="load" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" style="display: none" aria-hidden="true"></span> Save</button>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="edithButton" style="color:white;" onclick="doAction()" >Edith</button>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

Acá el archivo JS, en donde por JQUERY obtengo los datos que me deja el usuario, los asigno a sus variables, válido, hago un formData y lo mando en el AJAX:

```
function doAction(){

  var id_servicio = $('#id')[0].value;
  var id_tipo_servicio = $('#id_tipo_servicio')[0].value;
  var name = $('#name')[0].value;
  var desc = $('#desc')[0].value;
  var cost = $('#cost')[0].value;
  var img_url = $('#img_url').prop('files')[0];

    //insert
    console.log("INSERT - nombre: " + name + "desc: " + desc + "precio: " + cost + "id_tipo_servicio " + id_tipo_servicio);

    if(name === ""){ 
      $( "#name" ).focus();
      //document.getElementById("errorName").innerHTML = "Service Name is Required";
      $("#errorName").show();
      $("#errorName").html("Service Name is Required");
    }else if(id_tipo_servicio === "" || id_tipo_servicio === "0"){
      $( "#id_tipo_servicio" ).focus();
      //document.getElementById("errorName").innerHTML = "Service Name is Required";
      $("#errorName").hide();
      $("#errorSelect").show();
      $("#errorSelect").html("Service Type is Required");
    }else if(desc === "" || desc === "0"){
      $( "#desc" ).focus();
      $("#errorSelect").hide();
      $("#errorDesc").show();
      //document.getElementById("errorDesc").innerHTML = "Service Description is Required";
       $("#errorDesc").html("Service Name is Required");
    }else if(cost === "" || cost === "0"){
      $( "#cost" ).focus();
      $("#errorDesc").hide();
      $("#errorCost").show();
      //document.getElementById("errorCost").innerHTML = "Service Cost is Required";
      $("#errorCost").html("Service Cost is Required");

    }else{

      var formData = new FormData();

      formData.append('name',name);
      formData.append('id_tipo_servicio',id_tipo_servicio);
      formData.append('desc',desc);
      formData.append('cost',cost);
      formData.append('archivo',img_url);
      formData.append('function',"addService");

      $.ajax({
        data:  formData, //send data via AJAX
        url:   '../controller/serviceController.php', //url file controller PHP
        dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the server
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type:  'post', //send POST data
        beforeSend: function () {
          document.getElementById("load").style.display = "block";
        },
        success:  function (response) { //get request

        if(response.success){ 
          $("#successModalTitle").html("<i class='fas fa-check-circle color-success'></i> ¡Success!");
        }else{
          $("#successModalTitle").html("<i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle color-error'></i> ¡Error!");
        }
          $("#successModalDescription").html(response.message);

          //alert(response.message);
          $('#actionModal').modal('toggle');
          $('#services').DataTable().ajax.reload();
          $('.close').click(); 

        }
      });


      } 
}
```

Y de este lado esta el PHP, en donde recibo el AJAX cargado con el DataForm, asigno valor a sus respectivas variables, me conecto a la base, armo el INSERT y lo ejecuto **../controller/serviceController.php**:

```
if(isset($_POST['function']) && !empty($_POST['function'])) {

    $function = $_POST['function'];


    //En función del parámetro que nos llegue ejecutamos una función u otra
    switch($function) {

    case 'addService':
            # code...
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $cost = $_POST['cost'];
            $desc = $_POST['desc'];
            $id_tipo_servicio = $_POST['id_tipo_servicio'];
            $date = date("Y-m-d");
            $iva = 0;
            $status = 1;

            $nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
            $ruta = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
            $destino = ".../img/" . $nombre;

            require_once 'conn/connection.php';
            $connect = new connection();
            $connection=$connect->connections();


            $sql = "INSERT INTO servicios (id_tipo_servicio, ser_nombre, ser_descripcion, ser_img_url, ser_precio, ser_fecha_creacion, ser_fecha_actualizacion, ser_iva, ser_status) VALUES ('".$id_tipo_servicio ."','".$name."','".$desc."','".$destino."','".$cost."','".$date ."', '".$date."', '".$iva."', '".$status."');";


            $jsondata = array();

            if ($connection->query($sql)===true) {
                $jsondata['success'] = true;
                $jsondata['message'] = 'Felicidades! Has insertado el Servicio con Éxito.';

            } else {
                $jsondata['success'] = false;
                $jsondata['message'] = 'Error! Ha ocurrido un error, avisa a un administrador.';
            }
            //Aunque el content-type no sea un problema en la mayoría de casos, es recomendable especificarlo
            header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

            echo json_encode($jsondata, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);


            break;
}
}
```

¿Qué es lo que hace el código?

El código recoge los datos desde el HTML, va al JS cargado de datos, construyo un DataForm, lo lleno y esto se va en el AJAX, lo envía y ya en PHP es donde hay un error y esta raro porque, SI INSERTA, PERO NO ME DEVUELVE MENSAJE DE ÉXITO, el PHP regresa un false y me devuelve ERROR. **Insisto, pero si INSERTA.**

**Realmente no se porque no devuelve TRUE si no tiene problemas al INSERTAR**, ahora tampoco he logrado guardar el archivo en el servidor.

**Asi inserta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es el ERROR que muestra mi dashboard y esto es lo raro porque es **COMO SINO ENTRARA AL IF**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: verifica si en tu metodo $connection->query($sql)  realmente te regresa un valor true

Comment: Es la función query: Retorna FALSE en caso de error. Si una consulta del tipo SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE o EXPLAIN es exitosa, mysqli_query() retornará un objeto mysqli_result. Para otras consultas exitosas de mysqli_query() retornará TRUE.

Comment: consulta en que momento escribes la imagen en la ruta del disco, en php `$destino` solo es la ruta en texto???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando mandas los datos no estas haciendo nada con el archivo lo tienes que mover a la carpeta que definas como uploads y claro con los permisos suficientes de escritura.

```
if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
    @mkdir($targetDir,0755,true);
}
```

con este código verificas que exista la ruta y la crea su no existe

```
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $targetDir)) {
        echo sprintf('Error al mover el archivo %s para %s', $_FILES['archivo'['name'], $targetDir);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Entonces segun tu comentario solo deberias invertir el if

ejemplo:

```
if (!$connection->query($sql)) {
     $jsondata['success'] = false;
     $jsondata['message'] = 'Error! Ha ocurrido un error, avisa a un administrador.';            
} else {
  $jsondata['success'] = true;
  $jsondata['message'] = 'Felicidades! Has insertado el Servicio con Éxito.';                   
}
```

Comment: Si invierto el if sale lo mismo, date cuenta que en el MODAL de ERROR, no me manda el MESSAGE, es como sino entrara a ninguna parte del IF

Answer (score 0):

Te falta el `method`:

```
'POST'
```

en las opciones del ajax.

Comment: no es este: type:  'post', //send POST data | si lo tengo en el AJAX

Comment: Entiendo, con el archivo lo que pasa es que solo estas guardando la ruta, no estas moviendo el objeto de imagen que recuperas en el form. Y con lo del insert tendrias  que hacer un var_dump para ver que es lo que pasa o revisar algun log para ver especificamente cual es el error, podes probar con try catch o algun error callback de tu conexion a la db.